# liferay 6.1 indexer class not creating indexes in lucene

Tags: java, liferay-6, lucene

My overall goal is to use asset entry tags for taxonomy.  I accomplish this by adding a portlet to every page that has tags and such.

Now that I have that working , I moved to implement an indexer so that we can easily search for pages. Which I did as follows:

```
public class TaxonomyMetaIndexer extends com.liferay.portal.kernel.search.BaseIndexer {
public static final String[] CLASS_NAMES = {AssetEntry.class.getName()};

@Override
public String[] getClassNames() {
    return CLASS_NAMES;
}

@Override
public String getPortletId() {
    return "taxonomymeta_WAR_Portlets61201";
}

@Override
protected void doDelete(Object obj) throws Exception {
    AssetEntry entry = (AssetEntry)obj;
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    long companyId = entry.getCompanyId();
    long resourcePrimKey = entry.getEntryId();
    deleteDocument(companyId,resourcePrimKey);
}

@Override
protected Document doGetDocument(Object obj) throws Exception {

    AssetEntry entry = (AssetEntry)obj;

    long[] assetCategoryIds = entry.getCategoryIds();

    List<AssetCategory> categories = entry.getCategories();

    String[] assetCategoryNames = StringUtil.split(ListUtil.toString(categories, "name"));

    String[] assetTagNames =entry.getTagNames();

    Document document = getBaseModelDocument(getPortletId(), entry);
    document.addText(Field.DESCRIPTION, entry.getDescription());
    document.addText(Field.TITLE, entry.getTitle());

    document.addKeyword(Field.ENTRY_CLASS_PK, Long.toString(entry.getEntryId()));
    document.addKeyword(Field.ENTRY_CLASS_NAME,AssetEntry.class.getName());
    document.addKeyword(Field.COMPANY_ID, entry.getCompanyId());
    document.addKeyword(Field.GROUP_ID, entry.getGroupId());
    document.addKeyword(Field.PORTLET_ID, getPortletId());

    document.addKeyword(Field.ASSET_CATEGORY_IDS, assetCategoryIds);
    document.addKeyword(Field.ASSET_CATEGORY_TITLES, assetCategoryNames);
    document.addKeyword(Field.ASSET_TAG_NAMES, assetTagNames);



    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(AssetEntry.class.getName());
    System.out.println(entry.getTitle());
    System.out.println(entry.getDescription());
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();

    return document;
}

@Override
protected Summary doGetSummary(Document document, Locale arg1, String snippet,
        PortletURL portletURL) throws Exception {
    String title = document.get(Field.TITLE);

    String content = snippet;

    if (Validator.isNull(snippet)) {
        content = document.get(Field.DESCRIPTION);

        if (Validator.isNull(content)) {
            content = StringUtil.shorten(
                document.get(Field.CONTENT), 200);
        }
    }

    String resourcePrimKey = document.get(Field.ENTRY_CLASS_PK);

    portletURL.setParameter("jspPage", "/html/taxonomymeta/view.jsp");
    portletURL.setParameter("resourcePrimKey", resourcePrimKey);

    return new Summary(title, content, portletURL);

}

@Override
protected void doReindex(Object obj) throws Exception {
    AssetEntry entry = (AssetEntry) obj;

    Document document = doGetDocument(entry);

    //SearchEngineUtil.updateDocument(lo.getCompanyId(), document);
    SearchEngineUtil.updateDocument(SearchEngineUtil.GENERIC_ENGINE_ID, entry.getCompanyId(), document);
}

@Override
protected void doReindex(String[] arg0) throws Exception {
    long companyId = GetterUtil.getLong(arg0[0]);

    reindexRoot(companyId);
}

@Override
protected void doReindex(String arg0, long classPK) throws Exception {
    AssetEntry entry = AssetEntryServiceUtil.getEntry(classPK);
    doReindex(entry);
}

@Override
protected String getPortletId(SearchContext arg0) {
    return getPortletId();
}



 protected void reindexRoot(long companyId) throws Exception {

        int groupCount = GroupLocalServiceUtil.getCompanyGroupsCount(companyId);

        int groupPages = groupCount / Indexer.DEFAULT_INTERVAL;

        for (int i = 0; i <= groupPages; i++) {
            int groupStart = (i * Indexer.DEFAULT_INTERVAL);
            int groupEnd = groupStart + Indexer.DEFAULT_INTERVAL;

            reindexRoot(companyId, groupStart, groupEnd);
        }
    }

    protected void reindexRoot(long companyId, int groupStart, int groupEnd)
            throws Exception {

        List<Group> groups = GroupLocalServiceUtil.getCompanyGroups(companyId,
                groupStart, groupEnd);

        for (Group group : groups) {
            long groupId = group.getGroupId();
            // long folderId =
            // BookmarksFolderConstants.DEFAULT_PARENT_FOLDER_ID;

            int entryCount =AssetEntryServiceUtil.getCompanyEntriesCount(group.getCompanyId());

            int entryPages = entryCount / Indexer.DEFAULT_INTERVAL;

            for (int i = 0; i <= entryPages; i++) {
                int entryStart = (i * Indexer.DEFAULT_INTERVAL);
                int entryEnd = entryStart + Indexer.DEFAULT_INTERVAL;

                reindexEntries(companyId, groupId, entryStart, entryEnd);
            }
        }
    }


    protected void reindexEntries(long companyId, long groupId, int entryStart,
            int entryEnd) throws Exception {


        List<AssetEntry> entries = AssetEntryServiceUtil.getCompanyEntries(companyId, entryStart, entryEnd);

        if (entries.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }

        Collection<Document> documents = new ArrayList<Document>();

        for (AssetEntry entry : entries) {
            Document document = getDocument(entry);

            documents.add(document);
        }

        //SearchEngineUtil.updateDocuments(companyId, documents);
        SearchEngineUtil.updateDocuments(SearchEngineUtil.GENERIC_ENGINE_ID, companyId, documents);
    }


}
```

The call to index I use is :

```
String cat = "";

    Enumeration<String> names=actionRequest.getParameterNames();

    while(names.hasMoreElements())
    {
        String param = (String) names.nextElement();
        if(param.contains("assetCategoryIds"))
        {
            cat = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, param);
        }
    }

    String tag = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "assetTagNames");

    String[] tags = tag.split(",");
    String[] cats = cat.split(",");
    long[] catIds = new long[cats.length];

    if(cat.length() > 1)
    {
        for(int i =0;i < cats.length; i++)
        {
            catIds[i] = Long.parseLong(cats[i]);
        }
    }

    if(tag.length() == 0)
    {
        tags = new String[0];
    }

    ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay) actionRequest.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
    long id = themeDisplay.getPlid();
    long user = Long.parseLong(actionRequest.getRemoteUser());
    Layout layout = themeDisplay.getLayout();
    long group = layout.getGroupId();
    String pageName = layout.getName(themeDisplay.getLocale());
    String desc = layout.getDescription();
    String url = PortalUtil.getLayoutActualURL(layout);
    try {
        url = PortalUtil.getLayoutFullURL(themeDisplay);
    } catch (PortalException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SystemException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    String layoutUuid = layout.getUuid();

    try {

        AssetEntry entry = AssetEntryLocalServiceUtil.updateEntry(user,group,"Page",id,"",0, catIds,tags,true,null,null,new Date(),null,ContentTypes.TEXT_HTML,pageName,desc,desc,url, layoutUuid, 0,0,0,false);
        TaxonomyMetaIndexer index = new TaxonomyMetaIndexer();
        Document doc = null;
        try {
            doc = index.doGetDocument(entry);
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        SearchEngineUtil.addDocument(SearchEngineUtil.GENERIC_ENGINE_ID, layout.getCompanyId(), doc);

    } catch (PortalException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SystemException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I have also tried using

```
TaxonomyMetaIndexer index = new TaxonomyMetaIndexer();
index.doReindex(entry);
```

instead of searchengineutil.addDocument

this seems to run fine with no errors.  I have 3 basic test pages with asset entries.

However when using lukeall to view the lucene folder indexes I dont see any. :(

I have ran the server in debug mode and I can watch the code run into the indexer but no indexes are ever created.

Any help is much appreciated !!!!!

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: any liferayers out there?

Comment: can you try with SearchEngineUtil.SYSTEM_ENGINE_ID instead SearchEngineUtil.GENERIC_ENGINE_ID;